# is there a way to get python to open a series of folders

Tags: python

Basically, I am working with a HathiTrust database.  Part of the script I need needs to go into a workset folder containing tons of other folders, each containing a different data source. Within each of these folders, I want to create a text file that combines every text file in the folder into one text file, name it after the folder, leave the folder, and open the next folder and do the same.  This is on a remote desktop, so I don't know the absolute path.

Haven't found anything online but I've been looking at the os module.  I'm not sure if any specific module exists to open folders and not files, though

```
import csv

import glob
import os

f=open('volume-rights.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    volumeid=line
    path=os.path.dirname('/%/*.txt' %(volumeid))
    filename=os.path.basename(path)
    files = glob.glob('*.txt')
    for file in files:
        with open('%.txt' %(filename), 'w') as result:
            result.write(str(file)+'\n')
    result.close()
```

Comment: There is no opening folders. You can get the directory structure and write to a location (if you have permissions to do so).

Comment: What isn't working with your present attempt?  Do you really need this concatenation, or would a simply `tar` command do what you want?